# Is the type of Dremora summoned by the Sanguine Rose variable each time it is used?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just got the titular staff and it appears to summon a melee-type Dremora Kynreeve every time I use it. Will this ever change?

Comment: I'm inclined to believe the wikia article both the current answers cite is incomplete. I'll try to investigate more when I next am able.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Sanguine Rose is unique among conjuration staves in that the spell scales with level. So while the effect is the same (a melee Dremora, in Daedric Armor wielding a Daedric Weapon), the actual level of the summon increases as the Dragonborn gains in power.

**Edit:**

I finally found some more precise data. Even though the staff is unobtainable before level 14 in a normal game, there are appropriately leveled Dremora for that range.

```
Level   Dremora Summoned
1        Dremora Churl
12       Dremora Caitiff
19       Dremora Kynval
27       Dremora Kynreeve
36       Dremora Markynaz
46       Dremora Valynaz [sic]
```

**Original Answer:**

I'm not sure how many levels there are *total*, but if the earliest summon is a Dremora Kynreeve ([as per this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Conjuration_Spells#Conjure_dremora_lord_.3D_sanguine_rose_summon_dremora.3F)), [it is likely that there are **at most** four](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Dremora#Ranks): Kynreeve, Kynmarcher, Markynaz, and Valkynaz.

Of these, Kynreeve is confirmed at level 14 (the minimum level to start the quest), Markynaz [has been seen as early as level 30](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Conjuration_Spells#Conjure_dremora_lord_.3D_sanguine_rose_summon_dremora.3F), and [Valkynaz has been seen at 72](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Artifacts#Sanguine_Rose_affected_by_Player_level).

Comment: I think you should make it clear that all staves level with the user's, but conjuration has a unique case where the spells don't matter how good you are.

Comment: @raven - thank you; i felt the same way. both wikis' articles were lacking, and i only asked the question here after reading both and finding them thusly incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

> The Rose summons a Dremora Kynmarcher, Dremora Valkynaz or a Dremora
>   Markynaz to fight for the Dragonborn 60 seconds.

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sanguine_Rose

Comment: wow, within seconds of each other, with the same source too :P

Comment: I want my dragonborn hat!

Comment: If you get it first I will, of course, FUS RO DAH it off your head.

Comment: I find it hilarious that this answer was downvoted more than 2 years after I made it.

Comment: if it's any consolation my answer got hit too!

Answer (score -1):

It does change - it will summon either a Dremora Kynreeve, Dremora Valkynaz or a Dremora Markynaz when you use it.
[source: Elder Scrolls wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sanguine_Rose_%28Skyrim%29)

Comment: This is confusing. Your source states that it's a Dremora Kynmarcher, not a Dremora Kynereeve like you say, but Toast's source (who stated the correct Dremora) doesn't mention what you summon at all. I'm not sure who to upvote, as you have the right source and wrong info, and Toast has the wrong source but the right info.

Comment: You're right about the Kynmarcher/Kynreeve - I must have glanced over that. I'm actually not sure which is correct now - I can't find another source.

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Conjuration_Spells#Conjure_dremora_lord_.3D_sanguine_rose_summon_dremora.3F The discussion here implies it's a Kynreeve, though it's *also* incomplete.