# What is the difference between a Dremora summoned with the Conjuration spell and one summoned from the Sanguine Rose?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a character that is Level 37 and has 83 skill in Conjuration. I noticed that when I summon a Dremora with the [Conjure Dremora Lord spell](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjure_Dremora_Lord), the name of the summoned Dremora is 'Dremora Lord'.

However, when I use the [Sanguine Rose](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sanguine_Rose), to summon a Dremora, the name of the summoned Dremora is 'Dremora Markynaz'. What are the differences between the two?

According to the currently approved answer to this question: [Is the type of Dremora summoned by the Sanguine Rose variable each time it is used?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42917/is-the-type-of-dremora-summoned-by-the-sanguine-rose-variable-each-time-it-is-us) :

> The Sanguine Rose is unique among conjuration staves in that the spell scales with level. So while the effect is the same (a melee Dremora, in Daedric Armor wielding a Daedric Weapon), the actual level of the summon increases as the Dragonborn gains in power.
>
> I'm not sure how many levels there are total, but if the earliest summon is a Dremora Kynreeve (as per this), it is likely that there are at most four: Kynreeve, Kynmarcher, Markynaz, and Valkynaz.
>
> Of these, Kynreeve is confirmed at level 14 (the minimum level to start the quest), Markynaz has been seen as early as level 30, and Valkynaz has been seen at 72.

How does the Dremora Lord summoned by the Conjuration spell fit into the Sanguine Rose Dremora hierarchy? Is the Dremora Lord weaker (level-wise) than the Dremora Kynreeve or is it stronger than the Dremora Valkynaz?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At level 81, the Sanguine Rose will summon a Dremora "Valynaz" at level 46 with 545 HP. Its greatsword will have an enchantment of 15 point fire damage. Conjure Dremora Lord will summon a Dremora Lord at level 45 with 345 HP. Its greatsword will have an enchantment of 30 point fire damage. Both have 100 two-handed weapon skill and 84 heavy armor skill, leading to an underwhelming 183 armor rating.

All in all, Dremora Valynaz will be a bit more durable, while the Dremora Lord will have slightly greater damage output, due to the better enchantment.

Comment: @desaivv, I haven't experienced this firsthand, but do you have any spell absorption? It apparently can "eat" your summons.

Comment: @desaivv kotekzot is right. According to the [Conjuration UESP article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjuration#Bugs): "Currently a bug exists which causes Summoning spells to fail. As the spell appears to target yourself, any existing Magic Absorb can cause the Atronach or Dremora not to appear, "refunding" the casting cost for no net loss. This can be easily reproduced with a Breton's Dragonskin, Alteration's Atronach perk, or the Atronach Standing Stone. Magic Resist does not appear to have this effect."

Comment: @desaivv If you're playing on the PC,  the [Atronach stone and perk fix for conjuration](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=8308) mod should fix that bug.

Comment: Odd. On the PC I did a "Totally over the top massively OP" build using every console command I could lay my grubby mitts on, and I never had that problem. *furls brow** I am going to have to load Skyrim up again and see if I can recreate this issue.

Comment: The unofficial patch fixes this problem.  Also... this is a really old question.